# How do I set runtimerCompiler: true in Rails 6 when using Vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am running a Rails 6 project and have run into the error:

`[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`

I read that I should set the following code in the vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

I installed Vue through Yarn, so how do I actually set this property since I cannot find the config. Do I need to create this as a new file?